# SQL Query vs Querdsl

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

Other than the syntax-safe and type-safe in Querydsl, is there any special reason to use Querydsl in complex select operations rather than SQL queries? I am very new to Querydsl and I have seen in my company codebase they have used Querydsl only for the complex select operations, including summary search. Are there any special reasons for that?

Comment: Why are you excluding the reasons for using Querydsl when asking for the reasons to use Querydsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can write database independent queries using Querydsl.